# eBay LMS uploadFile - Cannot specify file with valid format

Tags: python, mime-types, ebay-api, ebay-lms, xop

I am attempting to use the eBay Large Merchant Services API to upload calls in bulk. This API and documentation are notoriously bad (I found a blog post that explains it and rails against it [here](http://medium.com/on-coding/dont-write-your-api-this-way-a1b745078b94)). The closest I can find to a working Python solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482135/http-post-request-and-headers-with-mime-attachments-multipart-related-and-xop) Question/Answer and his related [Github](https://github.com/wrhansen/eBay-LMS-API) version which is no longer maintained.

I have followed these examples very closely and as best I can tell they never fully worked in the first place. I emailed the original author and he says it was never put in production. However it should be very close to working.

All of my attempts result in a **error 11 Please specify a File with Valid Format** message.

I have tried various ways to construct this call, using both the github method, or a method via the email.mime package, and via Requests library, and the http.client library. The output below is what I believe is the closest I have to a what it should be. The file attached is using the Github's [sample](https://github.com/wrhansen/eBay-LMS-API/blob/master/examples/AddItem.xml) XML file, and it is read and gzipped using the [same methods](https://github.com/wrhansen/eBay-LMS-API/blob/master/lmslib.py#L326-L346) as in the Github repo.

Any help on this would be appreciated. I feel like I have exhausted my possibilities.

```
    POST https://storage.sandbox.ebay.com/FileTransferService
    X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME_boundary; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<0.urn:uuid:86f4bbc4-cfde-4bf5-a884-cbdf3c230bf2>"; start-info="text/xml"
    User-Agent: python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/3.3.4 Darwin/14.1.0
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN: **MYSANDBOXTOKEN**
    X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME: FileTransferService
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: uploadFile
    Content-Length: 4863


    --MIME_boundary
    Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:86f4bbc4-cfde-4bf5-a884-cbdf3c230bf2>

    <uploadFileRequest xmlns:sct="http://www.ebay.com/soaframework/common/types" xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services">
    <taskReferenceId>50009042491</taskReferenceId>
    <fileReferenceId>50009194541</fileReferenceId>
    <fileFormat>gzip</fileFormat>
    <fileAttachment>
    <Size>1399</Size>
    <Data><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:urn:uuid:1b449099-a434-4466-b8f6-3cc2d59797da"/></Data>
    </fileAttachment>
    </uploadFileRequest>


    --MIME_boundary
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <urn:uuid:1b449099-a434-4466-b8f6-3cc2d59797da>

    b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x1a\x98\xdaT\x02\xffuploadcompression.xml\x00\xcdW[W\xdb8\x10~\x0e\xbfB\x9b}\x858\xd0\xb4\x14\x8e\xebnn\x94l\xe3\x96M\xccv\xfb\xd4#\xec!\xd1V\x96\\I\x06\xfc\xefw$\xdbI\x9cK\x0f\xec\xbe,\xe5P{f\xbe\xb9i\xe6\xb3\xed\xbf\x7fJ9y\x00\xa5\x99\x14\xef\xda\xa7\x9dn\x9b\x80\x88e\xc2\xc4\xe2]\xfb6\xba:y\xdb~\x1f\x1c\xf9\x83\x9c\x7f\x1fQC\xc7O\xf1\x92\x8a\x05\xcc\xe0G\x0e\xdah\x82p\xa1\xdf\xb5s%.\xe1\x8e\x16\x974c\xfa\x12\x06\xd3\x01\xd50\x94i&\x05\x08\xa3\xdb\xc1Q\xcb\xbf\x06\x9a\x80\xc2\xab\x96\xffg\x1908\xef\x9d\xfb^}c\x15sf`2\nN\xbb]\xdf\xab\xae\x11\xe9\xad\xa1-\xbf\x9f$\x13\x03i\x95\xc1\x0b\x12 \x04\xd1c\xa5\xa4\x9ab\t9]@\x00\xe2\xdb\xed\xdc\xf7\x9a\xc2\xca\xf2\x0bU\x02\xbb0\x85\x07\xe0\xc15[,}\xaf!\xaa\xcc\x0e\x95\xd2\xf2C\xd0\x1a\xfda\t\x11&\x8a8\xf2\t\x1e\xc9\xdc({y%UJ\x8d\xef\xad\x8d\x10\x83\x0e}[\x9b\xc3\xb7\xfc\x88\x19\x0e\xc1\xf5\xefC2\xffz\x12\xf6\xff\xc2\xff\xec\xdf\xc9\x84\x9c\x91\xeb\xf14\x1cG\xa4\xff)\xba\x9e\xf5\x87\x93hLB/\x1c\x8f&\xb7\xa1\xef\x95\xb8\xd2\xc7\x08t\xacXflV\xd1\x92i\x82\xbf\x94\xc4Rr\xb2\x04\x9e\x829&\xccX\xe1\x9d\xa2"!\x023\xbc+\x88Y\x02y\xa4\xc5/\xbe\xb7\x89/=\xde(\x96RU\x0c\xa9\x81\x85TE)m\xf9\xf5=V\xf2\xe6\xbcw\xe1{\x1b\x82\x12\xe8\xedE\xfasC\x95AU\x0c\xc1\xc5E\xe7\x02\x91\x1b\x92\xd2d(E\xc2l\n\xe5h\xe0llJ\x8e\x1a\xf1C\x9ae\xd8\xe0>\xe7\xf2\x11\x92 R9\xacs\xd9R\xd6\xdesa0\x1d;\t\xf5u\xa5\xc9\x95\xc2m\xb0\xaa\x11\xea\xea\xbb\xaa\xb3Lg\xd4\xc4\xcb\x88\xa5\x10\xd2\xa7\xe0\x156kKT\x1aN\x99;\xfdQ\xae\xa8k\xe3\x88\x16\xfa\xdb)\x16\xb1\xadh\x98GE\x06\xc1\x15{\x82\xc4u\xc2\x8e\xc5\n\xe1t\xd5i\xd0"\xc5\x01\x0f\xc1,e\xa2\x03\xbc\xbd\xa1\x1c[\xdd\x14\xaflQ9N)\xe3\xb8D\n\'/\xb0+\xf3\x9bb\xb8\\:a:\xb6\xd5wb\x99:\x07\xdb\xb6\x95\x13\x16\x9b\\\xc1\x08\x0c\xaat}\xfa\x95\xf4v6\r\x96\xc6d\x97\x9e\x07\x9d]\xb7\x1e\x9e\xff\x02\xb4\x87#\xedu\xcf\xce\xce\xbbo\xbd\xd7\xe7oN^\xbf9\xfd\xa6\xd3\xce\xdf\xd9\x02\xe3\xae\x1d\xd5S\xb3\'\xa0\x7f#\xb5\xa1|(\x13\x08z\x17\xbd\xb3\x1e\x9a\xad%\xa5\xc9\x1f9\x15\x86\x99"\xb0\xad^\xdd\x94\xba\x19\xa0Kq#9\x8bW\x03<\x83\xfb\\$\x9f\xcbQ\xafy\xce\xf7\x1a\xe2\x86\xe9\x8e\xd1Zm\xbd\xeb/\xcc,\x99\xa8\x90\xe5\xa1\xf7\xac\xe9\xaer\x1f.8\xed\x11\x0b\xdaBl\xd9\xf6\xe3\x182\x03u~[\xd2\x15v\xcbl\xbf\x8f\x1aM\x0e\xc2k\xe0\x0e)\xb4\xeaV \xb9( \x19\xa8\x94\x19\x04\x1c\x13x\xb2P"\x05\x01\x0e\xb1QR\xb0\x18\x19\x07R}L,\xe1\xa49r\xf8\x1d\x10&p\x9dqK\x13\xf2\xe8\xea$X~\x82\xe5\x13yO\x14\xc4\x80\xd1:$\x04e\xc3\xe0H\xc1\x06\xd0\x91V\\\x13\x82\xc3\x13\xca9\xc9h\xfc\x9d.p]\x8eIJENy\x152\xa3\x98\xdf\xa3T\xdf\x11khl\x9c0\x17\x94\x1bP\x90tH$m\xd6\xae\x9cc\x92q\xc0\x07\x89u\xefLc\x8c*SPD\x83z\xc0\xb5$F\x96\xe9=\x00\xd2\xea,\xec\xff\xea\xbc\xc9\\\xad|\x90{\xa4\xfa\x0e\x19O\xc7\xc3h\xf6\xf9\xd3dH\x90\xad\xc3\xf91Ir\x07G\xaee\xe8/\x83\x98QN\x04\xb5\xc3Nb*\x84t\xf5\xd5n\x12\xeb\x07\x9d\x17\x18\x8fj\xac\xd3\xc6\xb1\xcd\xd6\x92\x03/0\xc3\x07\x9b>I\x18\xe6c\xb8\xe5p%\xf3\xc5\xb2\xf2\x8f\x1b\x8c\x11\x8c\xcd\xd36\xe3\x9e\xba\xa5R\xbaS\x1d\xe9.\xd1#3/\x99\xa3\xcb!\xae\xd6\re\xc9\xa0\xa8\xe6g\x90\x17\xa0\x90\xa7\x0f\xe9\x0f\xe2\x0f#\xebm\xdf\xdd\xcc\x95\x9b\r\x06X\xc9\xe6\xe51\x94qKr\xd8\xd6\x05\xf5}I\x86\xf8p\x11\tU\xc9:\x89\xda\xae\x19\xad\x92\xda\x0c\x83n\xa7\xbbc\xee\x14{!\xc8\x97n\x12-\x1b\x1d\x00o\x99\xecu\x83\xb4/\x95\xe3\xaf\x1d\xf8JU\x02\xc7O\x19\xa0?H\xeaJ\xeeq\xd6\x91\x95v\xe4\xae=W\n\xa0\xf6\x17\x18\xf7xl\x88l{\xbd\xc3\xfd\xf5\'\x02\xf7D\xd02\xfd\xbdv\x07\x8e\xa1j|\x03\xbf\xff\x14\xf6\x1d\x02\xae^\xf9\xf8\x9d\x8c\xf0\xc5t>j\x07g\xf8\xb6\xf0\xf6\xf0\xb9\x1c\xec\xe7\xd9\xcf\xfb\xe9p\x91\x9c\xca\xb8|*\x0f\xfb\xa5\xfd\x86\xc8\xb5\xe8y}\xf8\xff\xb4\xeb\xd5\xbfl\xd7\xab\x97\xb5\xab\x8f\xec\xc8b\xaa\xf75m\xc7x\x9c+\x99\xc1\xb3L\xfb\x9a\xd1\xe7\x19\xde\xfe\xa7\xf3\xaa5\xe5\xfb\x17\xb7\xef\xe8\r\xd1\x91[\xb8\x98\xe7\tlE\x99~\xb4+\xb7Os\x183\x19\xbd\x1c\x13~}9\xe6\xc3\xe0\xe5\x98\xf9\x87\x9fa\xe6\xc09\xa8\xbdz}\xa3\xe0\x1e\xec\xf4AE0\xcf4>\xda`\x9e\xe6\xfb\x9e\xfd\x16\x0c`@\x8bP\x1a\xa9t\xf9qX\xeb>\xde\xba\xaf\x02\xfc9\xb1\xbb\x8d\xb7n.\xbc\xfaS\xca\xf7\x9a\xdf\x8cVv\xe4{\x87\xbeiQ]\xff\xfb\x07\xe0\xf2E>\x1f\x0f\x00\x00'
    --MIME_boundary--
```

**EDIT:** Showing the methods I have tried to actually generate the binary data:

```
with open('testpayload.xml', mode='rt') as myfile:
        full_xml = myfile.read()  # replacing my full_xml with testpayload.xml, from Github repo

    # METHOD 1: Simple gzip.compress()

    payload = gzip.compress(bytes(full_xml, 'UTF-8'))

    # METHOD 2: Implementing https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507012/1281743 which should produce a gzip-compatible string with header

    import io
    out = io.BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
        f.write(bytes(full_xml, 'UTF-8'))
    payload = out.getvalue()

    # METHOD 3: Simply reading in a pre-compressed version of same testpayload.xml file. Compressed on commandline with 'gzip testpayload.xml'

    with open('testpayload.xml.gz', mode='rb') as myfile:
        payload = myfile.read()

    # METHOD 4: Adoping the _generate_date() function from github eBay-LMS-API repo http://goo.gl/YgFyBi

    mybuffer = io.BytesIO()
    fp = open('testpayload.xml', 'rb')  # This file is from https://github.com/wrhansen/eBay-LMS-API/
    # Create a gzip object that reads the compression to StringIO buffer
    gzipbuffer = gzip.GzipFile('uploadcompression.xml.gz', 'wb', 9, mybuffer)
    gzipbuffer.writelines(fp)
    gzipbuffer.close()
    fp.close()

    mybuffer.seek(0)
    payload = mybuffer.read()
    mybuffer.close()

    # DONE: send payload to API call

    r = ebay.fileTransfer_upload_file(file_id='50009194541', task_id='50009042491', gzip_data=payload)
```

**EDIT2, THE QUASI-SOLUTION:** Python was not actually sending binary data, but rather a string representation of binary, which did not work. I ended up having to base64-encode the file first. I had tried that before, but have been waived off of that by a suggestion on the eBay forums. I just changed one of the last headers to `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`  and I got a success response.

**EDIT3, THE REAL SOLUTION:** Base 64 encoding only solved my problems with the example XML file. I found that my own XML payload was NOT sending successfully (same error as before), but that the script on Github could send that same file just fine. The difference was that the Github script is Python2 and able to mix string and binary data without differentiation. To send binary data in Python3 I just had to make a few simple changes to change all the strings in the request_part and binary_part into bytes, so that the bytes from the gzip payload would concatenate with it. Looks like this:

```
binary_part = b'\r\n'
binary_part += b'--MIME_boundary\r\n'
binary_part += b'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n'
binary_part += b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n'
binary_part += b'Content-ID: <' + URN_UUID_ATTACHMENT.encode('utf-8') + b'>\r\n\r\n'
binary_part += gzip_data + b'\r\n'
binary_part += b'--MIME_boundary--'
```

So, no base64 encoding, just needed to figure out how to make Python send real binary data. And the original github repo **does** work as advertised, in python2.

Comment: Ok, here we go. First of all, let's see your XML that you're gonna be uploading as a file. Nvm i see the sample file

Comment: also try using production instead of sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after scanning all my code about this, it looks like it's setup right. So if your error is a good error then it means your binary data is wrong.  Can you show how you're gzipping and then reading that data back in?  Here's what I'm doing

```
$dir = '/.../ebayUpload.gz';
if(is_file($dir)) unlink($dir);
$gz = gzopen($dir,'w9');
gzwrite($gz, $xmlFile);
chmod($dir, 0777);
gzclose($gz);

// open that file as data;
$handle = fopen($dir, 'r');
$fileData = fread($handle, filesize($dir));
fclose($handle);
```

And in your case the $xmlFile should be the string found in https://github.com/wrhansen/eBay-LMS-API/blob/master/examples/AddItem.xml

I should add that this is how I'm using $fileData

```
 $binaryPart = '';
 $binaryPart .= "--" . $boundry . $CRLF;
 $binaryPart .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' . $CRLF;
 $binaryPart .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' . $CRLF;
 $binaryPart .= 'Content-ID: <urn:uuid:'.$uuid_attachment.'>' . $CRLF . $CRLF;
 $binaryPart .= $fileData . $CRLF;
 $binaryPart .= "--" . $boundry . "--";
```

Comment: I just added an edit to my original showing four different methods I have used to generate the binary data. All four give the same error message. I just re-tested them all using the AddItem.xml from the github repo, and tested all four on both Sandbox and Production servers (with sandbox/production job and file ID #s)

Comment: Can you post the GZ output? (or a part of it?) The reason I ask is because what you posted above  `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x1a\x98\xdaT\x02` is not the format of data that I have which is http://cl.ly/image/1G2h2I1x3d0J

Comment: also, make sure you're jobType matches the kind of file you're uploading.

Comment: All of the methods I use produce a bytes string that looks like the original question (with minor variations). I'm following up on this as a lead to see if it gets me anywhere. jobType is a match.

Comment: So, to confirm, you're gz data does NOT look like mine right?

Comment: If you open your .gz file in a text editor, what does it look like?

Comment: furthermore, here is my gz data opened in a text editor, and dumped out onto the page with var_dump http://cl.ly/image/371r0Z1i3j0Z  notice how neither of mine look like `\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x1a\x98\xdaT\x02`. So something is wrong with creating the gzipped data

Comment: It looks like it's just a difference in how Python was displaying the data to the screen. If I open the .xml.gz file in Sublime it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/xYUBPhk.png -- So I think we're back to square 1..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70808/discussion-between-sean-clark-and-nelluk).

Comment: Sean is correct that the problem ended up being the way Python was attaching my data. It wasn't actually sending binary, but just a string representation. I will add some clarifying information on the solution in an edit to the original question.